# Handle moving with CSplitterWindowImpl and invalidate child panes

Tags: c++, windows, wtl

I need to invalidate two panes when splitter is moving in WTL. Currently one of them invalidating when splitter is moving and other is invalidating when splitter moving stopped.
How can I handle splitter moving?

Answer (score 1):

You typically don't need to invalidate explicitly because splitter moves child windows and they receive regular messages like `WM_SIZE` causing UI updates. The question itself suggests that something is incorrect with child windows.

You certainly can overwrite splitter's `UpdateWindow` to handle end of splitter repositioning, but you don't normally need to do it. Splitter itself invalidates itself applies `SetWindowPos` to panes in its helper `UpdateSplitterLayout` method, which you can step through with debugger to make sure this code is being executed.

```c
LRESULT OnMouseMove(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    // [...]
            if(m_bFullDrag)
            {
                if(pT->SetSplitterPos(xyNewSplitPos, true))
                    pT->UpdateWindow();

bool SetSplitterPos(int xyPos = -1, bool bUpdate = true)
{
    // [...]
        UpdateSplitterLayout();

void UpdateSplitterLayout()
{
    // [...]
        for(int nPane = 0; nPane < m_nPanesCount; nPane++)
        {
            // [...]
                    ::SetWindowPos(m_hWndPane[nPane], NULL, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
```

You might want to ensure `m_bFullDrag` is set to `TRUE` to force repaints while moving is in progress.